# Excel - Need Function To Duplicate a List (complex formula)

Tags: excel, list, function, duplicates

I am trying to set-up an "auto-generating" worksheet for my company to use, but having difficulty getting this one function to work.

What I need is for a list of SKUs to repopulate in another list, but to be able to start taking the same values again once the list ends. This will be converted to **CSV** and used to import data on our website.

**Example:**

**Original List**

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Peach

I need this list to fill in cells on another list, but then duplicate the same values. See below.

**New List**

- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Peach
- Apple
- Banana
- Orange
- Peach

And then stop once the list is duplicated once. If there are 5 items in a list then it should stop after 10 items. If there are 8 items in a list then it should stop after 16. Order doesn't matter as long as the list gets duplicated.

I have tried `IF`, `VLOOKUP`, `HLOOKUP`, `COUNTIF`, `MATCH`, `INDEX`, but none of those or any combination of those I can think of have accomplished this. I just want to start taking values from the beginning of the list once the end of the list has been reached.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: So the idea is to automatically generate a list that contains each item in it twice and twice only? Would a VBA solution be acceptable, or do you want to avoid that?

Comment: Id like to avoid VBA because I need it to work with as little extra work as possible. VBA tends to become complicated and I dont want to have to explain how to use that. A formula will work as long as the only changes are made in designated cells.

Comment: Need two more comments

Comment: To get my next badge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Formula provides flexibility for the location of the ***"Original List"*** and the ***"New List"*** ranges.

Try this formula:

```
=T(INDEX(SrcCol,
-1+SrcRow+ROWS($TrgRow:TrgRow)
-IF(ROUNDUP(ROWS($TrgRow:TrgRow)/COUNTA(SrcCol),0)=2,COUNTA(SrcCol),0)))
```

Where:

**SrcCol**: Is the column where the *"Original List"* is located

**SrcRow**: Is the row where the *"Original List"* starts

**TrgRow**: Is the row where the *"Result"* list is starts

The formula assumes the *Original List* is has no blank cells in between.

Let's try the formula with the *Original List* starting at `B6` and we want the *New List* to start at `D3`. Then enter this formula in `D3` and copy down till last row (i.e. row 10):

Replace in the formula above the following:

**SrcCol**= `$B:$B`; **SrcRow**= `6` and **TrgRow**= `3`

```
=T(INDEX($B:$B,
-1+6+ROWS($3:3)
-IF(ROUNDUP(ROWS($3:3)/COUNTA($B:$B),0)=2,COUNTA($B:$B),0)))
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

If the *Original List* is the result of a formula and have cells returning a blank value (i.e. ="") then we have two options:

1. Replace `COUNTA($B:$B)` in the original formula with this `SUMPRODUCT(--($B:$B<>"")*COLUMN($A:$A))` and enter the resulting formula in `D3`:

   ```
   =T(INDEX($B:$B,
   -1+6+ROWS($3:3)
   -IF(ROUNDUP(ROWS($3:3)/
   SUMPRODUCT(--($B:$B<>"")*COLUMN($A:$A)),0)=2,
   SUMPRODUCT(--($B:$B<>"")*COLUMN($A:$A)),0)))`
   ```
2. Replace `COUNTA($B:$B)` in the original formula with this `SUM(--($B:$B<>""))` and enter the resulting formula as `FormulaArray` in `D3`:

   ```
   =T(INDEX($B:$B,
   -1+6+ROWS($3:3)
   -IF(ROUNDUP(ROWS($3:3)/
   SUM(--($B:$B<>"")),0)=2,
   SUM(--($B:$B<>"")),0)))
   ```

*`FormulaArrays` are entered pressing* <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> *simultaneously, you shall see* `{` *and* `}` *around the formula if entered correctly*

Comment: This one also works well, though I don't understand it at all. Specifically why you have the +1 and -6 values in the formula? Ive now encountered another problem - how to get these formulas to ignore a blank value even though there might be a formula in the cell. For example, B10's value is blank (""), but there might be a formula in the cell.

Comment: See Edit for the Formula results as blank (i.e ="")

Comment: Excellent. That is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, I have a solution, but there may be a more elegant way of doing this:

```
=IF(ROW()-1<=COUNTA($A$2:$A$5),INDEX($A$2:$A$5,ROW()-1),IF(ROW()-1<=(COUNTA($A$2:$A$5)*2),INDEX($A$2:$A$5,ROW()-1-COUNTA($A$2:$A$5)),""))
```

**Notes:**

- This assumes the list you want to duplicate is in A2:A5
- It also assumes the range where you want to copy to starts in row 2
  (hence the ROW()-1's)
- The forumla leaves a "" (empty quotes in cells with row numbers which are greater than two times the count of the list to duplicate. I don't think you can get past this unless you want to use VBA

Screenshot[image]

I'd suggest you could 'parameterise' the -1 using a [named range](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) or similar so that you don't have to change the -1 if you move things around.

Comment: I am impressed with how fast you figured this out. I spent half a day trying to get it to work. Im not too familiar with ROW, but it appears be solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: If I may ask another question. When you say 'parameterise' do you mean name a cell with the -1 value? Or simply rename the original list, but keep the -1 in the formula?

Comment: I'd name a cell something like 'startRow', and then that cell would have a value of 1, for my example, Id then replace the 1's in the formula with 'startRow'. It might not be worth doing unless you imagine you are going chop and change the workshop a lot.

Comment: If it was useful you could also 'paramterise' the list to duplicate so that it updates automatically without you having to change the formula

Comment: Ok, I see. But there is no way to get this formula to work with a different list location? If its not cells A2:A5, but maybe P32:P40.

Since ROW() applies to only A1... and it seems I can't add any cells in the (). This is not detrimental, as I'll just have to link the list to this range.

Comment: If the list to duplicated is P32:P40 the formula can be updated to: `=IF(ROW()-1<=COUNTA($P$32:$P$40),INDEX($P$32:$P$40,ROW()-1),IF(ROW()-1<=(COUNTA($P$32:$P$40)*2),INDEX($P$32:$P$40,ROW()-1-COUNTA($P$32:$P$40)),""))`. Note: You can use the ROW() function two ways. Firstly `=ROW()` will return the row number of the cell which contains the formula so A1 would be 1, G5 would be 5, A6 would be 6. The second way is `=ROW(F6)` which would give 6

Comment: I have tried to replace the range to P32:P40 and its just giving me the FALSE solution, which is blank. Also, the formula you post doesn't work for me with just a copy/paste. Furthermore, I don't have enough reputation to switch this discussion to chat. Makes no difference to me, but Im getting the warning to avoid extended discussions....